# Access a subclass' instance method from a superclass object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class that inherits from another class. The setup of the superclass is as follows:

```
class Creator::BaseResource < Creator::Base
  def request_attributes(action = :create)
    "super"
  end
end
```

And the subclass:

```
class Creator::Resource::HypervisorGroup < Creator::BaseResource
  def request_attributes(action = :create)
    "sub"
  end
end
```

Now, if I have an instance of "Creator::BaseResource", and there is a DB column named "resource_class" which contains "Resource::HypervisorGroup" that makes it known that its a subclass, I would like to be able to say object.request_attributes and get "super" returned, in this example.

The code is far more complicated than this, obviously, but that's the gist of what I want to accomplish. Is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: `object` refers to what in `object.request_attributes`? Object of `Creator::BaseResource` or `Resource::HypervisorGroup`

Answer (score 0):

What about that :

```
class Creator::Resource::HypervisorGroup < Creator::BaseResource
  def request_attributes(action = :create, use_super=false)
    super and return if use_super
    "sub"
  end
end
```

And then, you can call object.request_attributes(:create, true) to get the superclass method called